# PHPUnit\Framework\Exception Undefined offset: 43

Tags: admin-login, magento2.3.5-p1

I am running magento admin login test and i am getting error : "[PHPUnit\Framework\Exception] Undefined offset: 43"
Below are the logs:

```
1. // Entering Action Group [loginAsAdmin] AdminLoginActionGroup

#1  C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\magento2-functional-testing-framework\src\Magento\FunctionalTestingFramework\Codeception\Subscriber\Console.php:236
#2  C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\magento2-functional-testing-framework\src\Magento\FunctionalTestingFramework\Codeception\Subscriber\Console.php:165
#3  C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\magento2-functional-testing-framework\src\Magento\FunctionalTestingFramework\Codeception\Subscriber\Console.php:130
#4  C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\symfony\event-dispatcher\EventDispatcher.php:264
#5  C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\symfony\event-dispatcher\EventDispatcher.php:239
#6  C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\symfony\event-dispatcher\EventDispatcher.php:73
#7  C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\dev\tests\acceptance\tests\functional\Magento\_generated\default\AdminLoginSuccessfulTestCest.php:35
#8  Magento\AcceptanceTest\_default\Backend\AdminLoginSuccessfulTestCest->AdminLoginSuccessfulTest
```

Configuration:
Generate Tests Command Run
Codeception PHP Testing Framework v4.1.5
Powered by PHPUnit 9.1.5 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
Running with seed:

Any help would be highly appreciable.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. This is a special error occurs in case when you try to run tests on the Windows OS. In the files:

- *\vendor\magento\magento2-functional-testing-framework\src\Magento\FunctionalTestingFramework\Codeception\Subscriber\Console.php*
- *\vendor\magento\magento2-functional-testing-framework\src\Magento\FunctionalTestingFramework\Allure\Adapter\MagentoAllureAdapter.php*

you need to replace this line:

```
$this->testFiles[$filePath] = explode(PHP_EOL, file_get_contents($filePath));
```

with this code:

```
$this->testFiles[$filePath] = explode("\n", file_get_contents($filePath));
```

*Reason*: despite the variable *PHP_EOL* formally equals with this value in my environment (code trace of PHP_EOL in trouble line shows *define ('PHP_EOL', "\n");*), realy "\r\n" used, and *$this->testFiles[$filePath]* is not split into an array.

Comment: Thanks for providing the solution.